# Double hashing function returning wrong value

Tags: c++, dictionary, hash, double-hashing

I am creating a double hashing map, but the remove function does not work after inserting. I follow the same format for increasing the index, but it just does not hit the correct index.

```
class RHHM {
    unsigned int hash2( int key ) {

        return key % (M-1) + 1;

    }

    //Private variables

    hashNode ** map;        //Backing array
    unsigned int M;   //Capacity of array

    //If index that key hashes to is empty, insert. Else, replace value at hashed index.
    int insert( int key, char value ) {

        int f = hash( key );
        int f2 = hash2 ( key );
        int p = 0;
        int h = f + (p * f2) % M;

        while( map[h] != NULL ) {

            if( p == M )
                return -1 * p;

            if( map[h]->key == key ) {
                map[h]->value = value;
                return p;
            }
            else {
                ++p;
                h = f + (p * f2) % M;
            }
        }

        map[h] = new hashNode( key, value );
        return p;
    }

int remove( int key, char &value) {

        int f = hash( key );
        int f2 = hash2 ( key );
        int p = 0;                         //Keeps track of how many indexes have been checked
        int h = f + (p * f2) % M;

        while( map[h] != NULL ) {

            if( p  == M )              //If item is not found in table, return false
                return -1 * p;

            if( key == map[h]->key )        //If key is found, break out of loop
                break;
            else {
                ++p;
                h = f + (p * f2) % M;  //Wrap around array if necessary
            }

        }

        if( map[h] == NULL )                //If end of cluster reached, return false
            return -1 * p;

        value = map[h]->value;              //Stores the value of the item to be deleted
        delete map[h];                      //Delete the item the user specified
        map[h] = NULL;
        ++p;
        h = f + (p * f2) % M;
        for( ; map[h] != NULL; h = f + (p * f2) % M) {     //While still in the cluster, remove and     reinsert all items
            int tempKey = map[h]->key;
            char tempValue = map[h]->value;
            delete map[h];
            map[h] = NULL;
            insert(tempKey, tempValue);
            ++p;
        }
        return p;

    }

}
```

And here is my main:

```
RHHM bh(10);
bh.insert(0, 'A');
bh.insert(10, 'B');
bh.insert(20, 'C');
bh.print(std::cout);
```

Output:

```
<[ 0:A, - , 10:B, 20:C, - , - , - , - , - , - ]>
```

As you can see, the first index hashes to `0`. Since the `10` key collides with `0`, double hash ( `10` ) should hash to `1`, but its hashing to `2`.
Why is it returning the wrong value?

Comment: Why do you say it should be 1?

Comment: I guess your right. It should be hashing to 2. Either way, if I'm using the same increments for my remove function, why is it working (aka rehashing everything in the same cluster after deletion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the hash2 function returns a value 2 for the key 10.For hash2(10), hash2 can be shown as.

```
return 10 % (10-1) + 1
```

this in turn by operator precedence evaluated to the value 2 as.

```
return (10 %(10-1))+1
```

and in the insert function when there is a collision you add the hash2 value to the hash value to get the new index which evaluates as.

```
h= f + ( P * f2 ) % M
h= 0 + (1 * 2 ) % 10 \\ this evaluates to 2.
```

thats why you get the new index as 2.

Edit: The code has quiet a few issues with operator precedence.
First 
     h = f + (p * f2) % M;  //Wrap around array if necessary

This doesn't wrap around the array. since % has more precedence than +. f has value in the range[0-M-1] and the (p *f2) % M has values in the range [0-M-1]. So the above expression may evaluates to a value in the range [0-2*M-2]. This holds true for other such expressions in the code. This is a reason some of the key may be missing in hash table.

Comment: I understand. But.... why is the remove function not accessing the proper index to rehash after it removes the item specified?

Comment: can you provide a example of desired result after deleting a particular item

Comment: Yes. Deletion should rehash the items. The desired output after deletion of key 0 is: <[ 10:B, - , 20:C, - , - , - , - , - , - , - ]>

Comment: gman, I added parentheses to ensure operator precedence, and am having the exact same issues as before.